# How to convert the SQL geometry type to latitude (-90,90) and longitude (-180,180) in mssql?

Tags: python, sql-server, latitude-longitude, shapely, pyproj

I have a list of data with geometry column in the format of `0x6A7F0000010D340AF`.

I wand to retrieve the latitude and longitude in the range of `(-90,90)` and `(-180,180)`. I have tried the following code:

```
select geom.STY as lat, geom.STX as lon 
from Table;
```

However, it returns values in the range of `5058449.313` for latitude and longitude.

Any idea what I should do? Can I also use Python to do the conversion? How can I get the `CRS` from the geom?

**Update-Solution**

Assuming that I know the `CRS`, I can use this [code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78838/converting-projected-coordinates-to-lat-lon-using-python) to get the `latitude` and `longitude` from the `(Y,X)` retrieved from

```
select geom.STY as lat, geom.STX as lon 
from Table;
```

Answer (score 1):

STX and STY return X-coordinate and Y-coordinate property of a Point instance.
here is what you need:

```
SELECT  
    geom.Long AS [Longitude]
    ,geom.Lat AS [Latitude]
FROM [Table]
```

Comment: I have tried that and did receive the following error message:
Could not find property or field 'Long' for type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry' in assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types'.

Comment: oh so you are using wrong data type , you need to save data in `SqlGeography` datatype

Comment: I have been given the data. How can I convert it to `SqlGeography`?

Comment: I think by this function [STGeomFromText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stgeomfromtext-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thank you for your response. That code gets `latitude` and `longitude` and returns a `SqlGeography` type. Not what I need.

Comment: you can use something like this `SELECT geography::STGeomFromText([geom].STAsText(),4326)`

Comment: and it document it says it gets `geography_tagged_text` as input , why you says it gets long/lat , that is wrong interpretation .

Comment: Because of the example: ```DECLARE @g geography;  
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-122.360 47.656, -122.343 47.656)', 4326);
SELECT @g.ToString();```

Comment: that's just one example , did you try the one above? did it work?

Comment: Yes:  `The label 0x6A7F0000***** in the input well-known text (WKT) is not valid. Valid labels are POINT, LINESTRING, POLYGON, MULTIPOINT, MULTILINESTRING, MULTIPOLYGON, GEOMETRYCOLLECTION, CIRCULARSTRING, COMPOUNDCURVE, CURVEPOLYGON and FULLGLOBE (geography Data Type only).`

Answer (score 1):

Someone else has posted a proposed answer and the ensuing conversation has boiled down to "use `geography` instead of `geometry`". I agree!

But you also rightfully observe that you have what you have. And so my suggestion would be to get with whomever was responsible for *writing* the data and figure out how they stored latitude and longitude. That will get you a long way towards figuring out how to extract it from the extant data. Without knowing that, all you (and we) can do is speculate/guess.